# Escape semicolon in string when converting json to csv

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I am trying to convert the following data into csv format with headers equal to the keys in the json.

```
data= { 
        title: 'sample title',
        problem: 'this sentence; is a problem',  //<----
        name: 'Anitta',
        albumArt:'sample.png',
      }
```

I use [csv-writer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-writer) for converting json to csv.

My problem is that when the csv is generated the string with semicolon is split and inserted in 2 seperate cells. Instead I need it under the column `problem`.

### Expected result

```
title        | problem                     | name   | albumArt
-------------|-----------------------------|--------|------------
sample title | this sentence; is a problem | Anitta | sample.png
```

### Current Result

```
title        | problem        | name         | albumArt |
-------------|----------------|--------------|----------|----------
sample title | this sentence  | is a problem | Anitta   | sample.png
```

Is there any way that I could solve this??

### Edit

```
for (var key in data) 
  header.push({ id: key, title: key });
  const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
                path: `./output/${folderName}/${folderName}.csv`,
                header: header
            });
  csvWriter.writeRecords(data) // returns a promise
        .then(() => {
                console.log('Csv file created at :' + 
                `./output/${folderName}/${folderName}.csv`);
                resolve();
            });
```

Comment: Wrap the column in quotes, i.e. `"sample title";"this sentence; is a problem"; "Anitta"; "sample.png"`

Comment: The [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-writer) shows that strings containing spaces or delimiters are already wrapped in quotes. Can you show the exact code you're using?

Comment: @Kryptur — There's no reason to do that. It isn't JSON. It's JavaScript.

Comment: when you say "string with semicolon is split and inserted in 2 seperate cells" are you referring to excel?

Comment: let me edit the question @ChrisG

Comment: Please provide the actual CSV output, while you're at it :)

Comment: "Expected result" — I'd expect it to generate CSV, not any kind of table layout. I **suspect** that your real problem is a bug/misconfiguration in the software you are using to **parse** the CSV.

Comment: I opened in another application. It showed the data properly. Thank you @Quentin

Comment: Ok, so the CSV file was fine, but Excel screwed up?

Comment: Yes. Exactly @ChrisG

Comment: Just for the record; [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-cohen-2c0iy) opened in Excel works fine for me.

Comment: I opened in Libre Office initially. Then I opened in Wps spreadsheet, which worked fine. Later I realised that Libre office has an option where we can select the separators when a csv file is opened. Thank you @ChrisG for your effor :)

Answer (score -2):

its pretty easy try this

```
data= { 
        title: 'sample title',
        problem: '"this sentence; is a problem"',  //<----
        name: 'Anitta',
        albumArt:'sample.png',
      }
```

Comment: That's a really dirty hack, which largely defeats of the object of using a library to generate CSV in the first place.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56968812/escape-semicolon-in-string-when-converting-json-to-csv/56968934?noredirect=1#comment100475499_56968812

Comment: My friend, Glad to know that it is dirty but the only solution you got. I was also facing the same issue and after spending so much time, I thought of this solution and tried it out and fortunately it worked for me and due to that suggested same to you.